# Load big Excel (xlsx) file into matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I use Windows 64bit with 8GB RAM and Matlab 64bit.
I tried to load a .xlsx file into matlab. The file size is around 700MB, containing a sheet with 673928 rows and 43 columns.

First I use the GUI tool 'uiimport'. After choosing the file path and name, the GUI tool needs around 3 minutes to read the .xlsx file, and then shows the data in a table. If I choose "cell array", it needs around 10 minutes to import the data into workspace.

```
>>whos
Name                    Size                 Bytes     Class     Attributes
NBPPdataV3YOS1       673928x43            3473588728   cell
```

It works very well, but I have many .xlsx files to import. It is impossible to import each file using GUI tool. So I use the GUI tool to generate function like this

```
function data = importfile(workbookFile, sheetName, range)
%% Import the data
[~, ~, data] = xlsread(workbookFile, sheetName, range);
data(cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x) && isnumeric(x) && isnan(x),data)) = {''};
```

For simply, I ignore some irrelevant code. However, when I use this function to import the data, It does not work well. The used RAM by Matlab and Excel increases dramatically until almost all RAM is used. The data cannot be imported even after 30 minutes.

I also try to do it like this,

```
filename='E:\data.xlsx';
excelObj = actxserver('Excel.Application');
fileObj = excelObj.Workbooks.Open(filename);
sheetObj = fileObj.Worksheets.get('Item', 'sheet2');
%Read in ranges the same way as xlsread!
indata = sheetObj.Range('A1:AQ673928').Value;
```

The same problem occurs as xlsread().

My questions are:
1. Does the GUI import tool use xlsread() to read .xlsx file? If yes, why the generated function does not work? If no, which interface it uses?
2. Is there an efficient way to load Excel file into Matlab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be keeping the excel file in memory in Matlab. I would suggest looking into making sure you close the connection to each excel file after you have imported its data.

You may also find that the Matlab table class is more memory efficient than the cell class.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I restart Matlab each time, and kill Excel thread. But still the generated code by GUI import tool needs far more time than the GUI import tool itself.

Comment: Can you simply load the Excel file into Access, or better SQL Server, and read it into Matlab from there?

Comment: Also, if you save the .xlsx as .xlsb, the file size may shrink by as much as 4x.  Maybe, then, you can load it into Matlab.